# Avoid multiple useEffect on component on component load

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I building a simple like, bookmark functionality in my react app.

```
const [liked, setLiked] = useState();
const [bookmarked, setBookmarked] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    post.liked ?  setLiked(true):  setLiked(false);
    post.bookmarked ?  setBookmarked(true) : setBookmarked(false);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post(`${baseURL}/content/like`).then((res) => console.log(res));
  }, [liked]);
```

Whenever the component gets loaded it useEffect runs twice

How can I avoid intial axios post and axios post only if the state changes?

I want to send a post request whenever the `liked` State changes.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot avoid the `useEffect` hook from executing multiple times. The function will be called every time the `liked` value changes, however, you can check the `liked` value before calling `axios.post` to prevent making a request on the initialization state of the liked state:

```
const [liked, setLiked] = state(false);
...
useEffect(() => {
  if (liked) {
    axios.post(`${baseURL}/content/like`).then(res => console.log(res));
  }
}, [liked]);
```

Comment: I am handling both like and dislike in the same axios.post, So even like is false i want to send it to server for removing like

Comment: on a side note, I would also advise to use `async` `await` inside a try catch. Always catch errors on async calls. Your server could be down and you would probably like to give the user some error response.

Comment: @SudhakarBehera you should give your state a default as well then since you don't want it to be set from `undefined` to `false` since that is a state change and will trigger the state change. `const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);`

Comment: @JoeLloyd, yep i am using async await, for question purpose, i made is short

Comment: I have updated answer, I guess there is no need for checking liked to be true if you are setting it false once in state

Comment: what about when users dislikes the post, i have to make liked false, in order to inorder to remove red color on my heart icon

Comment: If there is no need to listen user disliking on server and you only need to update icon colour if user dislikes, then you can simply change liked value in state to false and implement logic to render icon without color in jsx

Comment: @SudhakarBehera Could you modify the question to describe the problem more fully? Or create a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `post.liked` is the current value in the backend, and you call `setLiked` on a button click or something as well, I would just compare if the state value is different from that current backend value:

```
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(post.liked);

useEffect(() => {
    if (liked !== post.liked) {
        axios.post(`${baseURL}/content/like`).then((res) => console.log(res));
    }
}, [liked, post.liked]);
```

Comment: In addition to that i want to change the liked status, for UI highlight heart icon, on the component , But if i do that it goes into to infinite loop

Comment: ah I think the issue is that you weren't setting your initial state value to `post.liked`, so every time it would render, `liked` wouldn't be equal to `post.liked`, which would cause the post to run, which would then cause a rerender, etc.

Comment: can i conditionally set 
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false); inside an if condition?

Comment: no you just do `const [liked, setLiked] = useState(post.liked)`;

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);
  const [bookmarked, setBookmarked] = useState(false);

  const handleLike = (likeStaus) => {
    setLiked(likeStaus);
    axios.post(`${baseURL}content/like`).then((res) => console.log(res));
  };
  const handleBookmark = (bookmarkStatus) => {
    setBookmarked(bookmarkStatus);
    axios.post(`${baseURL}content/bookmark`).then((res) => console.log(res));
  };

<button
          className={
            liked
              ? "meta-button btn btn-default text-danger btn-sm"
              : "meta-button btn btn-default btn-sm"
          }
          onClick={() => handleLike(!liked)}
        >
          <i className="lar la-heart"></i>
        </button>
```

I ended up using a separate function to handle like and bookmark
Since my post.liked is an array of users, I need inital `useEffect []` to check of user in array